# Spritebuilder project with wrong node positions in xcode 6

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode6, spritebuilder

I've been using spritebuilder to play around with a few design ideas. I recently upgraded xcode to xcode 6 and my node positions have ended up being a bit screwy. I was wondering if anyone else is having these issues.

What I get on spritebuilder vs how it ends up looking like on ios simulator 
[image]

Deploying to an actual ios device with ios 7 works correctly.

Comment: This is because neither cocos2d nor SpriteBuilder have been updated to be fully compatible with iPhone 6(+) yet. It was only just announced with actual specs revealed and updated Xcode released to simulate the new devices less than two days ago. The developers working on it are programmers, not magicians. ;)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D oh absolutely. I understand and figured this was most likely the reason behind the behaviour. I was just looking to see if anyone else was having the issue and had figured out a work around. I didn't mean to sound dickish in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the problem. unchecking all deivce orientations and checking protrait in xcode resolved it. I think somewhere along the way, spritebuilder is having difficulty setting correct device orientation on the new xcode.

### [image]

[image]